# Open a file without taking into account his extension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering How it should be possible to open a file with python without taking into account the extension.

For example, I have this line (it doesn't work I know because it doesn't exist a path with changelog.* file obviously):

```
with open(f"/home/user/Desktop/Projects/{app}/CHANGELOG.*", 'r') as changelog:
```

I would like to open changelog from a specific app (app1, app2, ...). In app1, changelog is `changelog.rst` but in app2, it's `changelog.md`.

How it will be possible to write in the `open()` function something like `/path/to/file/changelog.*` ?

I don't find something which could help me.

Comment: Maybe you can checkout the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/glob.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run through all files in the folder with `os.listdir()` or on a specific folder with `os.listdir(path)` and open a file with a certain name. Like this:

```
import os

path_to_file = "your/path/to/file"

for file in os.listdir(path_to_file):
    if (file.split('.')[0] == "changelog"):
        with open(os.path.join(path_to_file,file), 'r') as changelog:
            # Do something with file
```

The code above should work with any extension, not only `.rst` and `.md`. If you'd only want it to work with these two extensions, I think [@Rakesh's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56440408/8873143) answer is an easier approach.

Comment: This solution is better because more generalistic ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to check if the file with the extension exists.

**Ex:**

```
import os

exts = [".rst", ".md"]

for ext in exts:
    if os.path.isfile(filepath + ext):
        with open(f"/home/user/Desktop/Projects/{app}/CHANGELOG" + ext, 'r') as changelog:
            .....
```

---

or if you know the extension in each app you can use a `dict`

**Ex:**

```
exts = {"app1": "rst", "app2":"md"}
for app, ext in exts.items():
    with open(f"/home/user/Desktop/Projects/{app}/CHANGELOG.{ext}", 'r') as changelog:
        .....
```

Comment: Nice solution ! I don't know why I didn't think about that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using glob to allow you to find the full filename of the file before you open it.

```
import glob
import os

os.chdir(FILE_LOCATION) #if needed
files = glob.glob("CHANGELOG.*")

with open(files[0], 'r') as changelog:
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using python `glob` library for this requirement

here is the code:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('CHANGELOG.*');

for changelog in files:
   with open(changelog,'r') as f:
     # read f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def app(ext):
    changelog = f"/path/.../changelog.{ext}"
    return open(changelog, 'r')

app1 = app(rst)
app2 = app(md)
```